# Syncronous jquery call - How to wait until jquery method executed compete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, custom-component

I am new to jQuery.I am using Custom message Box. I have used [jQuery.msgBox()](http://jquerymsgbox.ibrahimkalyoncu.com/).

Now while i am trying to use it like

```
function myFunction(){

    $.msgBox({
       title:"Custom Alert",
       content:"Hello World!"
    });

   /* some code goes here */
   // For example 
   alert("executing after Custom Alert..");
}
```

Here both are called asynchronously, both Popups got show,

now i want first block of jQuery get executed first, then alert box should show.

somewhere i read Script is asynchronous, so is there any solution to call synchronously.

---

Yes this can be done using success / callback function..
but something i want to do like our basic 'confirm()' Method

```
var r=confirm("Press a button!")
if (r==true)
  {
  alert("You pressed OK!")
  }
else
  {
  alert("You pressed Cancel!")
  }
```

So it should work like...

```
function myConfirm(message){

 $.msgBox({
     title: "Confirmation !!",
     content: message,
     type: "confirm",
     buttons: [{ value: "Yes" }, { value: "No" }],
     success: function (result) {
        if (result == "Yes") {
            return true;  // kindly...i dont know this is proper way to return value.. 
        }else{
            return false; // kindly...i dont know this is proper way to return value.. 
        }
     }
  });
}
```

now when i call it like.. i want it like

```
var r = myConfirm("What do u like to choose?");

/* some operation will do on 'r' */
/* also to continue to next operation*/
```

after that, on the return value i will do next operation .
can this is possible to make our custom myConfirm() box method work like basic confirm() method.

Answer (score 2):

Try the below, give alert inside success function and check.

```
$.msgBox({
    title:"Custom Alert",
    content:"Hello World!",
    success: function () {
         alert("executing after Custom Alert..!");
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks Saranya !! this is one of the way... but kindly check my edit. i want it like basic confirm() method..

Comment: Give alert message instead of return true and return false.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use callback functions. you see success field? This is from jquery msgBox website.

```
$.msgBox({
    title: "Are You Sure",
    content: "Would you like a cup of coffee?",
    type: "confirm",
    buttons: [{ value: "Yes" }, { value: "No" }, { value: "Cancel"}],
    success: function (result) {
        if (result == "Yes") {
            alert("One cup of coffee coming right up!");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks lombausch !! kindly check my edit. i want it like basic confirm() method..